# Multi Tenant Application - Auto Create Database

Tags: c#, .net, azure, azure-sql-database

I have a multi tenant application which I am trying to deploy on Azure using a web app package.

When a user registers for a new account at that moment a database is created for them and this works flawlessly on my development machine with SQL Server 2014.

Do I need to configure the database server on Azure to allow this, if so how?

Comment: Only the owner of the account (you) have access to read/write data to the Azure Server.  Any other users can only access data by querying the webpage and using your credentials.  So you have to make sure any executable on Azure runs with your credentials.

Comment: @jdweng What are you talking about? This question has nothing to do with credentials; the OP isn't expecting the end-user to create a database (or if they are, I certainly didn't see that in the question). The OP stated the app is already working with SQL Server, and they're having issues with SQL Database service.

Comment: The title says "Create Database".  The OP is trying to "deploy on Azure".

Comment: The issue I am faced with is that programatically using Code First with a DB Initializer is not creating a database on azure for a new account. This process is working in a local instance, perhaps I need to adapt my code to talk with Azure to create the database instead of the `Database.Initilizer(new CreateDatabaseIfNotExisits())`?

Answer (score 0):

Not creating the database may be caused by a timeout.  See this post: [Entity Framework Database Initialization: Timeout when initializing new Azure SqlDatabase](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/35767530/entity-framework-database-initialization-timeout-when-initializing-new-azure-sq)

Answer (score 0):

If you need a new database to be created when someone signs up, you can better create the database before firing up Entity Framework.

This can be done using either T-SQL (1) when connected to the master database of your server or using the Azure Sql Managment Libraries (2). I would recommend option two since it will allow you to depend on a nice abstraction rather than interacting with the database directly.

1: https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/dn268335.aspx

2: https://www.nuget.org/packages/Microsoft.Azure.Management.Sql